# Module properties from xml, providing default values

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

If I have the following module:

```
class MyModule : Module
{
    public double SomeDouble { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the following autofac section in my `app.config`

```xml
<autofac>
   <modules>
      <module type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyNamespace">
         <properties>
            <property name="SomeDouble" value="" />
         </properties>
      </module>
   </modules>
</autofac>
```

When calling `builer.Build()`

I get an exception saying:

> Input string was not int the correct format, value is not valid for a
>   double

Which makes sense.

What I would like to be able to do is provide some kind of handler to handle the exception instead of making the whole `Build()` fail, or provide a default value.

Is this possible within autofac at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. The only solution I can see is to provide a custom `IConfigurationRegistrar` to the `ConfigurationSettingsReader`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader()
{
    ConfigurationRegistrar = new CustomConfigurationRegistrar()
});

builder.Build();
```

The `CustomConfigurationRegistrar` can inherits from the default [`ConfigurationRegistrar`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/blob/master/src/Autofac.Configuration/ConfigurationRegistrar.cs). 
If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/blob/master/src/Autofac.Configuration/ConfigurationRegistrar.cs), you can see that the `RegisterConfiguredModules` will register all module in a *foreach* loop, there is no method that register a single module, so you have to copy/past it from the base class.

Because the error come from the parameter used to inject the property, we can create a `LazyParameter` that will handle error and return default value.

```
public class CustomConfigurationRegistrar : ConfigurationRegistrar
{
    internal class LazyParameter : Parameter
    {
        public LazyParameter(Parameter originalParameter)
        {
            this._originalParameter = originalParameter;
        }

        private readonly Parameter _originalParameter;

        public override Boolean CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext context, out Func<Object> valueProvider)
        {
            Boolean canSupplyValue = this._originalParameter.CanSupplyValue(pi, context, out valueProvider);
            if (canSupplyValue)
            {
                Func<Object> originalValueProvider = valueProvider;
                valueProvider = () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return originalValueProvider();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(pi.Member.Name);
                        // log it and throw or return default value
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
            return canSupplyValue;
        }
    }


    protected override void RegisterConfiguredModules(ContainerBuilder builder, SectionHandler configurationSection)
    {
        if (builder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("builder");
        }
        if (configurationSection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("configurationSection");
        }
        foreach (ModuleElement moduleElement in configurationSection.Modules)
        {
            this.RegisterConfiguredModule(builder, configurationSection, moduleElement);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterConfiguredModule(ContainerBuilder builder, SectionHandler configurationSection, ModuleElement moduleElement)
    {
        try
        {
            var moduleType = this.LoadType(moduleElement.Type, configurationSection.DefaultAssembly);
            IModule module = null;

            IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters = moduleElement.Parameters.ToParameters().Select(p => new LazyParameter(p));
            IEnumerable<Parameter> properties = moduleElement.Properties.ToParameters().Select(p => new LazyParameter(p));

            using (var moduleActivator = new ReflectionActivator(
                moduleType,
                new DefaultConstructorFinder(),
                new MostParametersConstructorSelector(),
                parameters,
                properties))
            {
                module = (IModule)moduleActivator.ActivateInstance(new ContainerBuilder().Build(), Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());
            }
            builder.RegisterModule(module);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // log it
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it does seem like the only way at the moment. Good answer.